# Regular expression to match between two strings?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-2.7

Regular Expression to match everything between the date and the closing square bracket:

```
2018-09-19 15:15:27,272 - AppLog - INFO -
        ******************************************
        Log Report - Consume Cycle BWYgqW-ConsumeCycle
        ******************************************
        Uptime: 11723.089329242706s
        Jobs Run: 281098
        Jobs Current: 75
        Q Avg Read Time: 0.014049809202426435
        Q Msgs Read: 5347
        Worker Load: ['0.92', '0.95', '0.99']
        ******************************************

2018-09-19 15:16:42,089 - AppLog - INFO -
        ******************************************
        Log Report - Consume Cycle eehEes-ConsumeCycle
        ******************************************
        Uptime: 11710.040764093399s
        Jobs Run: 287010
        Jobs Current: 75
        Q Avg Read Time: 0.006846889048917865
        Q Msgs Read: 6649
        Worker Load: ['0.99', '0.99', '0.98']
        ******************************************
```

I have tried many regex to match between the `date`(2018-09-19) and closing square bracket `]` (including). 
The dates will be changing along with the year as well.

(I know that this is a repeated question but I am struggling a lot with this)

Comment: Have you tried refining your pattern at an online regex tester like regex101.com? show us your pattern and maybe we can point out what it needs.

Comment: Why dont you use a parser?

https://commandcenter.blogspot.com/2011/08/regular-expressions-in-lexing-and.html

https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/

Comment: The naivest approach would be `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}(.*\])` with the `re.DOTALL` flag, but since you didn't provide an expected output we can't really tell.

Comment: @DeepSpace don't you think the regex you gave will consume all the other dates in between, ie in the example given, it will just match once, while in real sense there are to blocks of date-] to be matched?

Comment: @Onyambu I posted the comment before OP edited the question and added another date section. However this can easily be fixed with a `?` after the `*`

Comment: @DeepSpace your answer is close to correct, except the date is not included in the match result. Got me really close to the answer though. Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `/[0-9]{4}[\s\S]+?\]/gm` would match what you want.

The `[0-9]{4}` search for the year at the beginning of the string, the `[\s\S]+?` would match anything until the first `]`.

The result would be:

```
Match 1
2018-09-19 15:15:27,272 - AppLog - INFO -
    ******************************************
    Log Report - Consume Cycle BWYgqW-ConsumeCycle
    ******************************************
    Uptime: 11723.089329242706s
    Jobs Run: 281098
    Jobs Current: 75
    Q Avg Read Time: 0.014049809202426435
    Q Msgs Read: 5347
    Worker Load: ['0.92', '0.95', '0.99']
```

---

```
Match 2
Full match  455-857 2018-09-19 15:16:42,089 - AppLog - INFO -
    ******************************************
    Log Report - Consume Cycle eehEes-ConsumeCycle
    ******************************************
    Uptime: 11710.040764093399s
    Jobs Run: 287010
    Jobs Current: 75
    Q Avg Read Time: 0.006846889048917865
    Q Msgs Read: 6649
    Worker Load: ['0.99', '0.99', '0.98']
```

You can test it on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/)

**[EDIT]** Removed `^` to use it with `re.findall` to get all the matches

Comment: This worked like a charm, except I had to remove the `^` from the regex to use it with `re.findall` to get all the matches